# Where do conditional comments get their info from?

Tags: html

Example:

```
<!--[if IE 6]>You suck!<![endif]-->
```

Does it get its information from the user-agent?

Comment: What information? That is a conditional comment with HTML, not CSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question yes it takes information from the user agent but I will just work in IE and it won't work when you change the user agent in chrome or ff.

See this picture is from my windows NT (virtual pc) from ie6:

[image]

And I changed the user agent in from ie6 in this picture and you can see:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

These are called `conditional comments`, and are only supported by IE, so in short, they're a feature of IE.

See http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html for a more elaborate explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Internet Explorer's own rendering engine / parser looks for these conditionals inside all HTML comments as it builds the DOM from the markup. So they can go anywhere and will be interpreted in the same order they appear.

Answer (score 1):

**This is only valid for Internet Explorer**. This will not be read from any other browser and will be **taken as comment** (that's why it is looking exactly as comment after all). It is not CSS but HTML comment, where IE knowns if the version match to do what is inside - to load css or something else.

It is a IE-specific (and other MS products) functionality only.

Addition: Such clause is used by Outlook also in HTML email messages: `<!–[if gte vml 1]>`

Answer (score 1):

According to MSDN, IE conditional comments are using Version Vectors that grab the version of IE and Windows Version that the browser is running on. The comments are basically skipped by Firefox and all different browsers since they sit inside an HTML comment. But as IE is supposed to read those, it basically does not skip those specific ones.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have it the other way around: the *browser itself* renders the CSS if and only if the browser can parse the instruction (in this case, the `[if IE]` instruction) it's not the server that is serving out dynamic CSS depending on the user-agent.